# how to do a MongoDB query and use it in a partial view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection called events that I am currently using in my footer partial, however, I would like to show only the ones with a date greater than today. I have achieved this on mongo shell like this:

```
db.events.find({date: {$gte: new Date()}})
```

I don't understand how to use this query in footer partial where I am running a loop to show the events, I would like to save this query in a variable that I can use in the loop, and it would be visible in every page of the website as they all have the footer.

To be able to use this collection in every page I am using this code in my app.js

```
// passing courses to every EJS template
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    Event.find({}, function (err, allEvents) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.locals.events = [];
            next();
        } else {
            res.locals.events = allEvents;
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

and this is where I am doing my loop in footer partial

```
<div id="event-footer" class="col-12  mt-4 mt-md-5 text-center col-md-4 text-md-left">
  <div class="">
    <h4 class="pb-1 pb-md-5">PROXIMOS EVENTOS</h4>
      <% var count = 0; %>
      <% events.forEach(function(event) { %>
        <% if (count <= 2 ) { %>
          <div class="eventDisplay text-center text-md-left">
            <h6><%=moment(event.date).format('dddd, D MMMM, h:mm a')%></h6>
            <p> <%= event.name %> </p>
          </div>
        <% } %>
      <% count++; }); %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to prevent code duplication of the footer?

Comment: Already sorted with the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Event.find({date: {$gte: new Date()}}, function (err, allEvents) { ...
```

Comment: well, that was easy... I tried before and didn't work! must've been a typo... I was complicating my life reading about promises etc, etc, but this did the job just fine thanks.